# Pass multiple calling arguments to a formal argument in dplyr custom function without using "..."

Tags: r, dplyr, quasiquotes

To make a custom function flexible to receiving one or more calling arguments per formal argument I currently rely on "...":

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(data, ..., dv){
  groups <- enquos(...)
  dv <- enquo(dv)
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
}

mtcars %>% foo(am, dv = mpg)
mtcars %>% foo(vs, am, dv = mpg)
```

But "..." obscures the logic of the function, and it could not be used in a custom function with 2 or more formal arguments requiring multiple calling arguments.

Is there a way to write the above function to utilize a formal argument (e.g., "groups") rather than "..." that can receive a single vector name or a vector of vector names as its argument(s)? Something like:

```
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){
  groups <- enquos(groups)
  dv <- enquo(dv)

  data %>% 
    group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
}

# Failing code
mtcars %>% foo(groups = c(vs, am), dv = mpg)
```

Note that this code would work, but require user to remember to use quos() in function body:

```
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){
  dv <- enquo(dv)

  data %>% 
    group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
}

mtcars %>% foo(groups = quos(vs, am), dv = mpg)
```

I'd love to rely on enquos() in body of function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could place the `...` at the end

```
foo <- function(data,  dv, ...){
   groups <- enquos(...)
   dv <- enquo(dv)
   data %>% 
     group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
     summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
  }
```

---

If we want to pass a `vector` of 'group', then one option is `group_by_at`

```
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){
  dv <- enquo(dv)

  data %>% 
     group_by_at(vars(groups)) %>% 
     summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
  }

mtcars %>% 
    foo(groups = c("vs", "am"), dv = mpg)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   vs [?]
#     vs    am group_mean
#  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     0     0       15.0
#2     0     1       19.8
#3     1     0       20.7
#4     1     1       28.4
```

---

One option if we want to pass unquoted expression with `c` would be to convert it to expression and then evaluate it

```
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){

 groups <- as.list(rlang::enexpr(groups))[-1]
 dv <- enquo(dv)
   data %>% 
      group_by(!!! groups) %>% 
      summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
 }

mtcars %>% 
      foo(groups = c(vs, am), dv = mpg)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   vs [?]
#     vs    am group_mean
#  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     0     0       15.0
#2     0     1       19.8
#3     1     0       20.7
#4     1     1       28.4
```

Or as @Joe mentioned in the comments, `enquo` should also work with `group_by_at`

```
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){
   dv <- enquo(dv) 
   groups <- enquos(groups) 
   data %>% 
        group_by_at(vars(!!!groups)) %>% 
        summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
   } 

mtcars %>% 
     foo(groups = c(vs, am), dv = mpg)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   vs [?]
#     vs    am group_mean
#  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     0     0       15.0
#2     0     1       19.8
#3     1     0       20.7
#4     1     1       28.4
```

Comment: Thank you, the function will work with a string vector and with quos(). Do you know if there is any reason it cannot work with enquos()? I can only find examples of enquos being used with "..."

Comment: @Joe  I updated with another option to convert it to an expression

Comment: your use of group_by_at() seems key to making this work, but I found that enquos() will also work: 
  
foo <- function(data, groups, dv){
  dv <- enquo(dv)
  groups <- enquos(groups)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(!!!groups)) %>% 
    summarise(group_mean = mean(!!dv))
}

mtcars %>% foo(groups = c(vs, am), dv = mpg)