# How to use a flexible, multi-argument filter within a dplyr custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

In a pinch, I can pass any number of arguments to filter using "...", but I find that "..." obscures the intention of the formal argument within the function, and this could confuse new or occasional users.

For instance, this function works, but I'd rather "..." be named 
 `filters` like in the second example (which doesn't work):

```
library(dplyr)

flex_filter <- function(data, ...){

  data %>% 
    dplyr::filter(...)
}

mtcars %>% flex_filter(mpg < 25, am == 1)
```

Ideally my function would look something like this. I realize enquos() is not appropriate for passing logical arguments, but it's in the spirit of what I am trying to do.

```
flex_filter <- function(data, filters){
  filters <- dplyr::enquos(filters)

  data %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!!!filters)
}

mtcars %>% flex_filter(filters = c(mpg < 25, am == 1))
```

Comment: Use a comment: `flex_filter <- function(data, ...){ # ... specifies filters`

Comment: You could pass in `filters = quos(mpg < 25, am == 1)` and then just jump straight to `filter(!!!filters)` but then you'd have to explain `quos` to the end-user. I'm stumped, but I'm sure someone cleverer than me will be along in a while.

Comment: @thelatemail, why do you think that quos() works, but enquos() in the body of the function does not? In a similar problem I used group_by_at() with vars(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160709/pass-multiple-calling-arguments-to-a-formal-argument-in-dplyr-custom-function-wi. But filter_at(vars(!!!filters)) was not working in this case.

Comment: @Joe - in all honesty, I couldn't say without sitting down for a while with a strong drink. I am very confused about tidyeval in general.